# responsive design css3 show on small screens not on large

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive-design

new to css3 media queries and responsive design.

I would like to know how to show something (say a div) on small screens only but not on large screens.
I've tried something like:

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.show-on-small-only{ display:block; visibility:visible;}
}
```

...
and anything larger has eg:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.show-on-small-only{ display:hidden; visibility:none;}
}
```

it doesn't seem to work as intended.

might be worth pointing out that i'm using bootstrap 2.0

Answer (score 6):

It's a better practice to make all your default style mobile-friendly and then use `min-` media queries to size up:

```
div { /*put whatever your default styles are first*/ }

/* Then use the media query to hide it at 481 and wider */
@media all and (min-width:481px) {
    div { display:none }
}
```

Look at [320andup](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/) and [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) and the CSS of [this page](http://responsejs.com/) for examples. Look at the helper classes towards the bottom of [this CSS](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/css/style.css) for differences between invisible/hidden etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this first

```
/* for small screens, only execute in if statement */   
@media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 768px) {
.smallOnly {
    visibility:visible!important;
    display:block!important;
}}
```

Then at the bottom of it put it for large screens (always execute since not in if statement)

```
.smallOnly {
visibility: none;
display: none;}
```

The important tg makes it so that anything with important always overwrite everything else and it will be the master rule regardless of where it is in the file.